# Importing text files with comments in MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab, file-io, import, comments

Is there any character or character combination that MATLAB interprets as comments, when importing data from text files? Being that when it detects it at the beginning of a line, will know all the line is to ignore?

I have a set of points in a file that look like this:
[image]

And as you can see he doesn't seem to understand them very well. Is there anything other than // I could use that MATLAB knows it's to ignore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the function [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html), you can set the `CommentStyle` parameter to `//` or `%`.  Try something like this:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
iRow = 1;
while (~feof(fid)) 
    myData(iRow,:) = textscan(fid,'%f %f\n','CommentStyle','//');
    iRow = iRow + 1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

That will work if there are two numbers per line.  I notice in your examples the number of numbers per line varies.  There are some lines with only one number.  Is this representative of your data?  You'll have to handle this differently if there isn't a uniform number of columns in each row.

Comment: I put them with 2 numbers per line(as they will always be) and still doesn't work.

Comment: It's reading one line at a time.  I modified my response to read to the end of the file.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, your data is not consistent, as you must have the same number of column for each line.

### 1)

Apart from that, using '%' as comments will be correctly recognized by **importdata**:

#### file.dat

```
%12 31
12 32
32 22
%abc
13 33
31 33
%ldddd
77 7
66 6
%33 33
12 31
31 23
```

#### matlab

```
data = importdata('file.dat')
```

### 2)

Otherwise use **textscan** to specify arbitrary comment symbols:

#### file2.dat

```
//12 31
12 32
32 22
//abc
13 33
31 33
//ldddd
77 7
66 6
//33 33
12 31
31 23
```

#### matlab

```
fid = fopen('file2.dat');
data = textscan(fid, '%f %f', 'CommentStyle','//', 'CollectOutput',true);
data = cell2mat(data);
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `%`, the default comment character in MATLAB?

As Amro pointed out, if you use `importdata` this will work.