# Remove lines from a .txt with a certain character in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file

I am working on a project with the data of magnitude of variable stars and I have come across a problem:

The data I have in a .txt document has a lot of comments marked with the symbol `#`, I would like to know if there is a way to read the whole text and take just the lines that does not include this particular character, I have already read the whole text and put into an array:

```
fid=fopen('000006+2553.txt','r');
i=1;
while 1
    tline=fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(tline), break, end
    A{i}=tline;
    i=i+1;
end
```

but from there I don't know how to follow.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902138/importing-text-files-with-comments-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a

```
if tline(1)=='#', continue, end
```

to your loop. That's quite a standard snippet.

**note** I just check the first character on purpose, as I have come across data files that contain comments *after* data in the same line. Also (valid) string fields might include the character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strfind](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) to check if a line contains #, for example

```
 if ~isempty(strfind(tline, '#'))
     continue;
 end
```